# Annotate a `selected_related`'d object in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am building a queryset of a model, and want to put an annotation on a related model that I am `selected_related`'ing into the queryset.  Hypothetically:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
```

I am selecting `Book.objects.all().select_related()`, and want to annotate the authors with `awesome=True`.  I *could* resolve the queryset and alter the objects myself, but is there a cleaner ORM-oriented way to do it? Inverting the operation to select the Authors instead is undesirable.

Comment: According to the model design please update your under with your expected query output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) may be more suitable and clean solution.

```
from django.db import models

q = Book.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    models.Prefetch(
        "author",
        queryset=Author.objects.all().annotate(
            awesome=models.Value(
                True,
                output_field=models.BooleanField()
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This will result in two queries to the database, instead of one with `select_related`, the second one being made when you access `.manager`, still only two queries in total, not additional one for every book to get its manager,
unless different queryset (i.e. with filters) in used while accessing `.manager` later.

Comment: Hunh, I had totally missed the bolded part:



"prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related, **in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by select_related**."

Thanks!